# Onsen UI with Fastclick

Tags: onsen-ui

I have read release notes last month that Onsen UI uses fastclick now.

I am not sure if this is used automatically or if I need to instantiate it.

Does anyone have or know if I need to do this as when I try click event son a touch screen it still feels like it has the usual 300ms delay.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is instantiated automatically. You don't have to instantiate it.

https://github.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/blob/master/framework/js/setup.js

Could you make a plunker so we can reproduce it?
Here is a template plunker to start with.
http://plnkr.co/edit/D2PBF8?p=info

Note: In the plunker, although, the script src says it's pointing to version 1.0.3, it is actually 1.0.4

Answer (score 1):

I think fastClick is applied automatically as long as you adopt Onsen UI.

However if you feel the response is slow, create a directive would solve the problem as following. This directive will apply touchstart event instead of default click event.

```
myApp.directive('onsFasttap', function() {
    return function(scope, element, attrs) {
        //You can replace the 'touchstart' event with 'touchend' one.
        element.bind('touchstart', function() {
        scope.$apply(attrs['onsFasttap']);
    });
  };
}


<button ons-fasttap="foo()">foo</button>
```

The above directive set the touchstart event to any element.